# Text editor to view giant log files

Tags: windows, logging, large-files

As I have not yet setup some log rotating solution, I have a 3gb (38-million line) log file which I need to find some information in from a certain date. As using cat  | grep  is horribly slow, and using my current editor (Large Text File Viewer) is equally slow, I was wondering: Is there any text editor that works well with viewing >35-million line log files? I could just use the cat | grep solution and leave it running overnight, but with millions of errors to sort through there has to be a better way.

Comment: You are unlikely to find a solution much faster than grep, but you don't need the cat.

Comment: I agree with grep. Also vim for windows .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try using `grep` by itself:

```
grep 2011-04-09 logfile.txt
```

instead of needlessly using `cat`:

```
cat logfile.txt | grep 2011-04-09
```

When dealing with large amounts of data, this can make a difference.

Interesting reading is a Usenet posting from last year: [why GNU grep is fast](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019310.html).

Comment: Thanks, using grep under cygwin is really fast.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on Windows, you should really try multiple implementations of `grep`.  Not all implementations of `grep` are equal.  There are some truly awful implementations.

It is not necessary to use `cat`:  Grep can read directly from the log file, unless it is locked against being shared with readers.

`grep` *pattern  logfile*  `> tmpfile`

should do the trick.  Then you can use most any editor to examine the selected records, assuming it is quite selective.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're going to get any faster than grep alone (as others have noted, you don't need the cat).

I personally find "more" and "less" are useful (for smaller files). The reason is that sometimes a pattern will get you in the general vicinity of where you want (i.e. a date and time) and then you can scroll through the file at that point.

the "/" is the search command for regular expressions in more.